# I have a problem of null pointer Exception in servlet 

Tags: jsp, servlets

HI, all

I have a problem of null pointer Exception in servlet .
I have a form a.jsp with check box if I do not select this check box and submit form then null pointer exception is occur in a.servlet.
How I Can handle this Exception

code 
a.jsp

```
<table border='0' width='50%' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' ><form name=form1 method=post action=aservlet >
<input type=hidden name=todo value=post>

<tr bgcolor='#ffffff'><td align=center >
<font face='verdana' size='2'><b>Sex</b><input type=radio name=sex value='male'>Male </font>
<input type=radio name=sex value='female'><font face='verdana' size='2'>Female</font></td></tr>

<tr><td align=center bgcolor='#f1f1f1'>
<font face='verdana' size='2'><input type=checkbox name=agree >I agree to terms and conditions </font>
</td></tr>

<tr bgcolor='#ffffff'><td align=center >
<input type=submit value=Submit>
 <input type=reset value=Reset>
</td></tr>
</form></table>
```

aservlet.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;


public class Admin extends HttpServlet {
        public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException,IOException 
            {
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
request.getParameter ("agree");
}}
```

Exception:

exception

java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.centralvisa.servlets.Admin.doPost(Admin.java:26)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

Thanks

Comment: This is not the complete code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few information. Problably you are accessing  the parameter without checking if it's sent.

Try with something like this in your servlet:

```
boolean checked=false;
if(request.getParameter("checkbox")!=null && 
   request.getParameter("checkbox").equals("checkbox_value_for_true")) {
    //your code for the checkbox value
    checked=true;
}
//the rest of your code use the var checked and not the request.getParameter()
```

Answer (score 0):

When a checkbox is not selected, the request parameter for the checkbox, (in your case) 'agree' does not exist i.e. **request.getParameter("agree") will return null.**

If you assigned request.getParameter("agree") to some String variable, and then called a method on this String, you will get a NullPointerException.

Solution is to check for null before assigning the parameter value.

Simply

```
if (request.getParameter("agree") != null ){
    // do stuff

}
```